# Pass values from container view to parent view controller

Tags: ios, uicontainerview, swift3.2

Im new to swift and i would like pass an array from my container view to parent view.I have created the container view using story board, but the container view appears and disappears programatically as shown below:

```
//in parent view controller, inside viewDidLoad()
CameraView.isHidden  = true

//in child view controller, on click of button,
let parent = self.parent as! DiaryEntryViewController
parent.CameraView.isHidden  = true
```

I want the data selected to be shown whenever i click the button to display container view.
I don't know how to pass values from child view controller to parent view controller and where can I should be able to access the values.These values need to accessed inside a function which is called on click of another button inside parent view controller.

Comment: Use protocols to communicate with your parent view controller and mark delegate in it

Comment: Can you suggest how it can be done, may be with some code. Im new to swift.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Steps to do that.

1. Your container view must contain a embed segue to the child view controller, name that segue something like this.... "homeToContainer" (See the attached Image)
   [image: Add Embed segue name]
2. Add this method to your parent View controller (DiaryEntryViewController )

   ```
   override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
           if let vc = segue.destination as? ChildViewController,
               segue.identifier == "homeToContainer" {
               vc.delegate = self
           }
   }
   ```
3. Add Protocol and its variable in ChildViewController:

   ```
       protocol ChildToParentProtocol:class {


           func buttonClickedByUser()
           func needToPassInfoToParent(with value:Int)

       }


       class ChildViewController: UIViewController {

           weak var delegate:ChildToParentProtocol? = nil

           @IBAction func createTourPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
               // Call here delegate methods to tell parent about the action
               delegate?.buttonClickedByUser()

           }

       }
   ```
4. In the last in your parent ViewController, add this Extension:

   ```
           extension DiaryEntryViewController:ChildToParentProtocol {

               func buttonClickedByUser() {

               }
               func needToPassInfoToParent(with value:Int) {


               }
           }
   ```

Comment: Can it be done without using segues? May be programatically?

Comment: If you added a container view in storyboard, then it must be connected via segue.

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't add it using storyboard.Im not adding container view anywhere. I'm just displaying the container view as hidden or not.

Comment: I have updated my answer, See screenshot for segue, are you doing in the same way?

Comment: Is there a way in which i can use data got from extension in main controller.?

Comment: You can do the same in extension as you can do in Main Controller, Just perform the code in functions present in the extension. 

Or 

Simply you can add this protocol as you define TableViewDelegate

Comment: where is "homeToContainer" defined? This is confusing

Answer (score 1):

If you added container view programmatically, you should use call back to get back values from container view to parent view.

**Parent Controller:**

```
let containerView = UIView()
containerView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
view.addSubview(containerView)

NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
    containerView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, constant: 0),
    containerView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor, constant: 0),
    containerView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: headerView.bottomAnchor, constant: 0),
    containerView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor, constant: 0),
    ])

let controller = YourViewController(nibName: "YourNibView", bundle: nil)

//This is important to get value back and also define callback to container view call as well
controller.callback = { result in
    self.isCardJoinedFromJoinScreen = true
    self.viewWillAppear(true)
}
addChild(controller)
controller.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
containerView.addSubview(controller.view)

NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
    controller.view.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.leadingAnchor),
    controller.view.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.trailingAnchor),
    controller.view.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.topAnchor),
    controller.view.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.bottomAnchor)
    ])
```

**Container View Controller**
define this callback

```
var callback : ((Bool)->())?
```

and at the point when you pass value to parent controller call this callback like

```
self.callback?(true) or self.callback?(false)
```